# setup blazor debugging on production server

Tags: debugging, blazor, production

I have a Blazor WASM asp.net core hosted project and a Windows Server VPS, There is an exception that only occurs on This server. I've tried many times to reproduce the error on my local machine with no luck. how should I debug a Blazor WASM project's (Client Code) on my production environment. I've tried publishing my asp project with debug config and using alt+shift+d but my project threw an exception

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1        Cannot start debugging, because the application was not compiled with debugging enabled.
```

What is the procedure to enable alt + shift + d on production server?

BTW this is the exception I'm getting and there is no sign of it in my Local system or staging server:

```
icrosoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: ConstructorParamIncompleteBinding, Void .ctor(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Tuple`2[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Filters.FilterType,System.String]], PShop.Presentation.Shared.PaginatedResultDto`1[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Products.ProductCardDto]), System.Tuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Tuple`2[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Filters.FilterType,System.String]],PShop.Presentation.Shared.PaginatedResultDto`1[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Products.ProductCardDto]]
System.InvalidOperationException: ConstructorParamIncompleteBinding, Void .ctor(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Tuple`2[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Filters.FilterType,System.String]], PShop.Presentation.Shared.PaginatedResultDto`1[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Products.ProductCardDto]), System.Tuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Tuple`2[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Filters.FilterType,System.String]],PShop.Presentation.Shared.PaginatedResultDto`1[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Products.ProductCardDto]]
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_ConstructorParameterIncompleteBinding(ConstructorInfo , Type )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectWithParameterizedConstructorConverter`1[[System.Tuple`2[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Tuple`2[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Filters.FilterType, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[PShop.Presentation.Shared.PaginatedResultDto`1[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Products.ProductCardDto, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& , Type , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& , Tuple`2& )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Tuple`2[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Tuple`2[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Filters.FilterType, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[PShop.Presentation.Shared.PaginatedResultDto`1[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Products.ProductCardDto, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& , Type , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& , Tuple`2& )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Tuple`2[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Tuple`2[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Filters.FilterType, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[PShop.Presentation.Shared.PaginatedResultDto`1[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Products.ProductCardDto, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[Tuple`2](JsonConverter , Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[Tuple`2](JsonReaderState& , Boolean , ReadOnlySpan`1 , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& , JsonConverter )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.<ReadAsync>d__20`1[[System.Tuple`2[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Tuple`2[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Filters.FilterType, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[PShop.Presentation.Shared.PaginatedResultDto`1[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Products.ProductCardDto, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.<ReadFromJsonAsyncCore>d__3`1[[System.Tuple`2[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Tuple`2[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Filters.FilterType, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[PShop.Presentation.Shared.PaginatedResultDto`1[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Products.ProductCardDto, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at PShop.Presentation.Blazor.Shop.Services.HttpDecorator.BaseHttpDecorator.<HandleResponse>d__13`1[[System.Tuple`2[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Tuple`2[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Filters.FilterType, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[PShop.Presentation.Shared.PaginatedResultDto`1[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Products.ProductCardDto, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at PShop.Presentation.Blazor.Shop.Services.HttpDecorator.BaseHttpDecorator.<Post>d__4`2[[System.Tuple`2[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Tuple`2[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Filters.FilterType, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[PShop.Presentation.Shared.PaginatedResultDto`1[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Products.ProductCardDto, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Tuple`2[[PShop.Presentation.Shared.Filters.FilterType, PShop.Presentation.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at PShop.Presentation.Blazor.Shop.Services.Filter.FilterService.Filter(ICollection`1 filterRequests, Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, String search, FilterSort sort)
   at PShop.Presentation.Blazor.Shop.Store.FilterUseCases.FilterEffects.OnFetchFilter(FetchFilters action, IDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Fluxor.Blazor.Web.StoreInitializer.OnAfterRender(Boolean firstRender)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IHandleAfterRender.OnAfterRenderAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.NotifyRenderCompletedAsync()
```

Comment: See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61406).

Comment: Hi, Any luck to enable alt + shift + d?

Comment: IDK if it was bug or a problem with my csproj file or a change in my launch settings or startup.cs but the issue solved on it's own after some time not sure if a vs update fixed it or it was somthing else